# Determinants of non homogenous

Tags: linear-algebra

If a derminant of a non-homogenous system is zero does it mean it MAY have no solution?

Because one of the lines has to be independent which means it may be zero and that zero line might be equal to a number which makes no solution.
 E.g. $$ (0 0 0 0 5)$$

and $0 \ne 5$

Comment: Anyone?  Thx on advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you are referring to the determinant of the coefficient matrix, and that this matrix is square (the determinant function is only defined for square matrices). If so, then yes, you are correct...when you row reduce the system you will have at least one zero row in the coefficient matrix, and it is possible that the augmented system will not have any zero rows - an inconsistent system which has no solutions.